# C# var keyword confusion: Type 'object' does not contain a definition for... error

Tags: c#, var, type-inference

I was writing this piece of C# code:

```
static void Main()
    {
        List<string> matches = new List<string>();
        var result = Regex.Matches(myString, @"\((.*?)\)");
        foreach(var x in result)
            matches.Add(x.Groups[1].Value.ToString());
    }
```

and I was surprised to see it fail with this error message:

> Type 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Groups' and no
>   extension method 'Groups' of type 'object' could be found.

However, this works:

```
foreach(Match x in result)
    matches.Add(x.Groups[1].Value.ToString());
```

The `Matches()` method returns a `MatchCollection`, shouldn't it be clear that `x` is a `Match`?

Comment: I ran into this a couple of weeks ago as I was transitioning to C# and basically came to the conclusion that I had to explicitly set the type for x as it was not easily apparent what result could hold so the compiler keeps it as a base object which, of course, doesn't have a definition for Groups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> shouldn't it be clear that x is a Match?

Sadly no.

`MatchCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, the non-generic legacy interface. It does not implement `IEnumerable<Match>`.  So no, that is not clear.

Because the `foreach` loop was designed in an era before generics, it automatically inserts a cast to the loop variable type.  That is

```
foreach(Match x in result)
  matches.Add(x.Groups[1].Value.ToString());
```

is the moral equivalent of

```
IEnumerator enumtor = result.GetEnumerator();
while (enumtor.MoveNext())
{
    Match x = (Match)(enumtor.Current);
    ...
```

You could have said

```
foreach(Giraffe x in result)
```

and it would have compiled just fine, and died at runtime.

When you say

```
foreach(var x in result)
```

The compiler sees that there is no type information to infer beyond object, so that's what it gives you for the type of x. Your error then follows from there.

I do not know why the collection has not been updated to make it more amenable to static typing; you'd have to ask the BCL team.

Comment: @Eutherpy - You can explicitly convert the `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<Match>` using [`Cast<Match>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx). This will let you keep your `var`.

Comment: *I do not know why the collection has not been updated to make it more amenable to static typing;* I do not think it is possible to do such update. `foreach` designed to use class own `GetEnumerator()` over `IEnumerable<T>.Enumerator()`, and `MatchCollection.GetEnumerator()` return `IEnumerator` and you can not change it without breaking compatibility.